# MVC 3 + WebGrid: paging controls don't show

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, webgrid

I am having problems with paging a WebGrid.  Essentially, I pass the full data, it pages OK.  If I limit the data to one page at a time, the paging controls disappear, despite the fact that I have passed in the rowCount.

Why?

See below for setup:

I have a grid defined as follows:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Cuentas";
    var grid = new WebGrid(defaultSort: "AccountName", rowsPerPage: 30, canPage: true, 
        ajaxUpdateCallback: "updateGrid");
    grid.Bind(source: Model.Accounts, rowCount: Model.TotalRows);
}
```

With its columns defined as follows:

```
<div id="grid">
    @grid.GetHtml(tableStyle:"grid",headerStyle:"head", alternatingRowStyle:"alt", htmlAttributes: new { id = "AccountsGrid"},
        columns:  grid.Columns(grid.Column(header: "", format: (item) => Html.ActionLink("Editar", "Edit", new { id = item.AccountId })),
                                grid.Column(header: "", format: (item) => Html.ActionLink("Eliminar", "Delete", new { id = item.AccountId })),
                                grid.Column("AccountName",header:"Nombre"), 
                                grid.Column("IsClient", header:"Cliente?"), 
                                grid.Column("IsProvider", header:"Proveedor?"), 
                                grid.Column("IsBank", header:"Banco o Caja?"),
                                        grid.Column("Person", format: item => new HtmlString(item.Person == null ? "" : item.Person.Name), header: "Contacto"),
                                        grid.Column("AccountsCostCentress", 
                                            format: item => new HtmlString(item.AccountsCostCentress == null ?
                                            "" : item.AccountsCostCentress.Count.ToString()), header: "Actividades")))
</div>
```

The ViewModel I am using in my view is defined as follows:

```
public class AccountsListViewModel
{
    public int PageSize { get; set; }
    public int PageNumber { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Account> Accounts { get; set; }
    public int TotalRows {get;set;}
}
```

This shows that I can pass the rowCount and the IEnumerable Accounts.

Lets say I have 305 rows of accounts.  If I set PageSize to 30, that means I will have 11 pages of data (the last one will only have 5 records on it).  If Accounts holds all 305 records, the grid works with paging and all.

**If Accounts only holds the 30 records corresponding to page 3, for example, the paging control don't show, EVEN IF TotalRows == 305.**

Can't figure it out.  Can you?  Or do you know of a blog post, thread or article I might look at??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry!  Answered my own question:

autoSortPage: false parameter missing from grid.Bind(...) method.

See the following SO thread:

[WebGrid paging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4185464/asp-net-mvc-3-webgrid-paging-issue)